# Determinant of a decomplexified matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries $$z_{ij} = a_{ij} + I*b_{ij}$$
If AR is its $2n \times 2n$ decomplexified matrix, i. e. the matrix with entries $a_{ij},b_{ij}$

Is it possible to compute det(AR) from det(A) or viceversa?

Comment: For $n=1$ the matrix $A=(i)$ would correspond to a $2\times 2$ matrix with entries $0,1$, right? Have you written down the matrix already? Certainly the determinants are different, but one might see how they are related.

Comment: @ mathreadler:  Thanks, very useful.